# Autohide panel?

Tags: panel

Is there any way to get a panel to ALWAYS stay auto-hidden? I have Ubuntu Studio 21.04. I have my panels set to autohide. EVERY TIME I open a program, the panel un-autohides itself and intrudes onto the monitor, with the newly opened program highlighted as though it needs attention. I click on it, the program comes into my foreground, the panel autohides again, and I open the panel to find the program that I was working on in the first place. It is surprisingly cumbersome when using dual monitor and opening a program that opens in multiple windows, like a restored session of Firefox or Zoom, which opens in three windows. (The program doesn't have an action waiting or anything. It's just freshly opened, stays in the background, and immediately highlights itself in the panel, thinking that it needs attention.) I think it might stay autohidden if the computer would open programs in the foreground instead of the background. But better still, I would like to set it so it doesn't think every freshly opened program needs attention. The weird thing is that when a program really does have a popup window waiting on input, the panel doesn't always unhide. Worst of both worlds, under my current settings.

Answer (score 0):

In the panel properties, you can select 3 Auto-hide modes:

- always
- never
- intelligent

I think your mode is set to "intelligent".